# How to implement a trait for any iterable type?

Tags: iterator, rust, traits, generic-programming, generic-collections

I'd like to implement a generic method that's callable on any container or iterator that iterates over a specific type, e.g. `&[u32]`, `Vec<u32>`, `(0..99u32)`, etc.

[The following code](http://is.gd/FyPn2I) does not compile:

```
trait Foo { fn foo(self); }

impl Foo for std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=u32> {
    fn foo(self) {}
}
```

> error: the value of the associated type `IntoIter` (from the trait `core::iter::IntoIterator`) must be specified [E0191]
>
> ```
> impl Foo for std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=u32> {
> ```

What needs to be specified for the `IntoIter` associated type? (`std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=u32,IntoIter=???>`)

so that this would work:

```
vec![0u32].foo()
```

Comment: Note: `IntoIterator` is in the prelude; you don't need the `std::iter::` prefix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax here is `impl<T> SomeTrait for T where T: OtherTrait`. This works:

```
trait Foo { fn foo(self); }

impl<T> Foo for T 
    where T: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item=u32> 
{
    fn foo(self) {}
}

fn main() {
    vec![0u32].foo()
}
```